# Center element within element

Tags: css, center

I'm trying to center this element here: https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5508d4ee693f59d0072198d7/1191x701/f94f2503ad54439174bed54e3630041d/ScreenShot_20150318203417.png

Can someone help me please? The link of this page is http://margaridamoreira.com/welcome/. Which CSS could fix this?

Best,
Ivo

Comment: Your HTML goes in the question.  Isolate it, repro it, add it in an [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for the `ul` and `li` in the `media=all` css selector

```
.sharify-container ul{padding:0;margin: 0 auto;display: inline-block;width: 100%;height: 100%;text-align: center;}

.sharify-container li{list-style:none;height:50px;line-height:30px;float: none;margin:0;padding-left:2.5px;display: inline-block;}
```

Using `float:left`, you are aligning all the `li` elements to the left of the `ul` which is not what you want here.